# Installing a nodejs module without using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi i have a  module which i have tar.gz and kept in a directory.When i executed the below command

```
npm install foo.tar.gz -g
```

My folder did not get installed it threw me an error saying that my folder is not available in npm registry.Is there any other way to install without using npm,am stuck here.Any help will be much helpful

Comment: `npm install ./foo.tar.gz -g`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install a module **locally**:

- create a `node_modules` folder in the root of your project
- extract the module (and its dependencies) in an extra folder in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Node modules are just folder. When you use

```
npm install mymodule
```

You're just getting a folder in your node_modules folder
So just extract your module in a folder with the desired name under the node_modules directory

Comment: Oh. Aren't global modules Just the same thing but inside your node installation folder?